# What might be happening with these strings in terms of character encoding in C#? They compare differently when read from different sources

Tags: c#, regex, soap, character-encoding, soapui

I have written a custom web application that copies *collections* of files from one data source and transfers them to Office 365 (SharePoint). The application I am taking the files from has a SOAP based API for retrieving filenames and other metadata - so I assume the messages returned to my app are in UTF-8. They certainly seem to be when I test the service in SoapUI.

<s>When I pass those same filenames through a C# `string` primitive, through the SharePoint Client Object Model and effectively save them to a SharePoint library, I seem to be getting slightly different text in the resulting filename.</s>

**Edit:**
Correction to the above - I am using the SOAP service to get information about the files in the first instance, but there is a separate ASHX web handler that provides me with the files themselves. The files are a in `Zip` format, and I am using the `ZipArchive` class to read them. It is possible that I am instantiating this class incorrectly or that filenames are being returned differently from the applications' web service vs the actual filenames in the Zip files. If the latter is the case, I may have to go back to the software vendor to get clarification on what is happening.

To illustrate the issue:

SoapUI told me that one file had a regular hyphen `-` (char code 45) - but when I looked at the resulting file in SharePoint, it was recorded as an em-dash `–` (char code 8211). I have found a similar incongruity - I have found two different types of ampersand, opening and closing apostrophe characters (`‘` and `’`), and various types of space (non-breaking, em etc) all screwing up my filename comparisons.

My routine needs to compare the two data sources to check if re-synchronisation is necessary, but because the stored name appears to be different to what comes from the API - I'm having to do some ugly, hacky-feeling Regex to compare the filenames. Luckily I can also compare against an originating ID so I'm more assured I'm looking at the right file(s) - but I was just wondering - is there a better way to compare strings of this type and take this sort of thing in to account?

```
var matchingFile = matchingItem.Attachments.Where((item) =>
{
   string spFilename = (string)li["OriginalFilename"];
   string filename = item.FileName;
   if (spFilename == filename) return true;

   // Handling differences in dashes/hyphens with this regex
   string dashRegex = @"[\p{Pd}]";
   spFilename = Regex.Replace(spFilename, dashRegex, "-");
   filename = Regex.Replace(filename, dashRegex, "-");

   // Handling differences in bracketing quotations, apostophes, ampersands and spaces with this one
   string otherRegex = @"(?=[^.])[\p{Pi}\p{Pf}\p{Po}\s]";
   spFilename = Regex.Replace(spFilename, otherRegex, "");
   filename = Regex.Replace(filename, otherRegex, "");

   return spFilename == filename;
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

That last regex allows me to ignore the variants in space-characters, apostrophes and so forth. It's working, but it feels hacky and like there should (or probably is) some better way. I feel like I might just be missing something in the initial transfer when I first read the filename...

Should I be converting or parsing the SOAP response as another encoding or something? The service reference for the SOAP requests was generated by dotnet-svcutil if that has any significance...

Comment: Through away your hack.  It is just a kludge do to some other issue.  One of two things is happening.  1) You should not be converting to strings.  Some intermediate transfer of data should be copying Bytes 2) You are applying the wrong encoding.  The data my be unicode and you are using UTF-8.  The best way of debugging is to track the byte count has code moves from one location to another.  The byte count should always be the same.  It the byte count grows or shrinks than that is where the error is occuring.

Comment: Yeah it feels that way. To clarify - (just checked my code again) - the SOAP service gives me information only, about collections of files on the other application... let's call them records. That's just filenames, byte count, content type etc. I can pass the IDs of each record to an ASHX handler on the same box to read the data as a stream - if its multiple files, the stream should be read as a Zip file, I'm using the `ZipArchive` class for that... It's here I get the byte array and filename for each file -- based on your suggestion, I think I might be instantiating ZipArchive incorrectly 1/2

Comment: Looks like [`ZipArchive` has a four argument constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Compression_ZipArchive__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_IO_Compression_ZipArchiveMode_System_Boolean_System_Text_Encoding_) that takes a specific Encoding for entryNames (aka filenames!)... I feel like that's got to be it. But I'll follow your suggestion and track the bytes as it passes through the rest of my code too. Thanks 2/2

Comment: It looks like the SOAP web service might be giving me different filenames to what is actually present in the zipped archive from the web handler. In that case I think I need to know what transforms or encodings the software vendor is doing to the filenames before it passes them over the web service and apply the same logic... if I can confirm something like that is happening, I'll update and close this question